# flowlistview refreshing dosent stop

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

i have this method:

```
public async void Load()
{
    this.IsRefreshing = true;
    // await CODE
    this.IsRefreshing = false;
}
```

Porperty IsRefreshing is working fine (INotifyPropertyChanged its OK).
The first time i run Load method took some time and the flowlistview shows the activityindicator until load is completed, but next times load method is too fast and it seems the (IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}") is not working and the activityindicator keeps spinning.

IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True".

Im calling Load() in the constructor.

Comment: Is this method in your viewmodel or in your code-behind class? Have to tried to do a Task.Delay to simulate waiting, to check if the problem is really the "fast" load?

Comment: Is in the viewModel, i added Task.Delay(200) (before this.IsRunning = false) an it works!. thank you for your suggestion. 
Im gonna keep it like that.
Anyway i think theres somthing wrong with xamarin or my way of coding.